# SQL validation with AND condition multiple values from php/html file

Tags: php, sql, database

Help me which code is better in the below.

There are 5 $program1, $program2,..... in the php/html file.

First method: mutliple AND conditions, is that good?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE univ_name='$univ_name' AND program='$program1' AND program='$program2' AND program='$program3' AND program='$program4' AND program='$program5'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck < 1) {

    //my code goes here
}
```

Second method: i don't know if this works and inserts values in the database.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE univ_name='$univ_name' AND program='$program1, $program2, $program3, $program4, $program5'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck < 1) {

    //my code goes here
}
```

Comment: are you sure you want to use a `AND` on the same field with different values ? if the first condition passes, there is no way the other will pass so you will never get results

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `AND` instead of `OR`? because that might always don't return any result from your where condition.

Comment: only AND can give me the result i want.

Comment: so you are looking for somebody named foo and 20 years old and 30 years old ? many *and conditions* on the same field are a nonsense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to get all the rows where program is one of the values in your `$program` vars, you can use `IN` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE 
    univ_name='$univ_name'
    AND program IN (
        '$program1',
        '$program2',
        '$program3',
        '$program4',
        '$program5'
    )";
```

Comment: exactly this is what i wanted. Awesome. You saved me.